# Hide text in an html label that consists of text and image

Tags: html, css

I have the following label:

```
<label for="payment_method_new">
New <img src="www.example.com/img.png"/>    
</label>
```

What I would like to do is to only hide the text inside the label, but to display the image.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) style for that.

First have your label's content hidden using `hidden` or `collapse`, then show your image using `visible`:

```
label[for="payment_method_new"]{
    visbility: collapse;
}
label[for="payment_method_new"] img{
    visibility: visible;
    float: left;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6owvftxh/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but the text still takes up its space. Is there any way for img to be in the beginning of the label?

Answer (score 1):

```css
#hidet {

  visibility: collapse;

}

#hidet img {

  visibility: visible;

}
```

```html
<label id='hidet' for="payment_method_new">
  New
  <img src="www.example.com/img.png" />
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works but the text still takes up its space. Is there any way for img to be in the beginning of the label?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific purpose of first writing text 'New' within your label and then hiding it?

There could be another way of retaining both image and text in your html code, still not showing the text -

```
<img src="www.example.com/img.png" alt="New" />
```